# wxpython demo code richtextctrl

Tags: wxpython

I am developing a program using wxrichtextctrl. I am stuck on setting font for a selection. After lot of googling I found the wxpython demo where I found a sample.Following is the original code from wxpython demo which is generating an error.

```
  def OnFont(self, evt):
    if not self.rtc.HasSelection():
        return

    r = self.rtc.GetSelectionRange()
    fontData = wx.FontData()
    fontData.EnableEffects(False)
    attr = wx.TextAttr()
    attr.SetFlags(wx.TEXT_ATTR_FONT)
    if self.rtc.GetStyle(self.rtc.GetInsertionPoint(), attr):#line is generating error
        fontData.SetInitialFont(attr.GetFont())

    dlg = wx.FontDialog(self, fontData)
    if dlg.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:
        fontData = dlg.GetFontData()
        font = fontData.GetChosenFont()
        if font:
            attr.SetFlags(wx.TEXT_ATTR_FONT)
            attr.SetFont(font)
            self.rtc.SetStyle(r, attr)#generating error
    dlg.Destroy()
```

I am getting error
   if self.rtc.GetStyle(self.rtc.GetInsertionPoint(), attr):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\wx-2.9.4-msw\wx\richtext.py", line 3121, in GetStyle
 **TypeError: in method 'RichTextCtrl_GetStyle', expected argument 3 of type 'wxRichTextAttr &'**.

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\wx-2.9.4-msw\wx\richtext.py", line 3111, in SetStyle
    return _richtext.RichTextCtrl_SetStyle(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: in method 'RichTextCtrl_SetStyle', expected argument 3 of type 'wxRichTextAttr const &'

I am using windows xp and wxpython 2.9 python 2.7. In the demo also the font and color does not work.
The getstyle and setstyle are generating error. Apparently because of this the font and color does not work in richtextctrl demo in wxpython demo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That example code you found may be for an older wxPython version which is why it doesn't work.

replace:

```
attr = wx.TextAttr()
```

with:

```
attr = wx.richtext.RichTextAttr()
```

That works for both `wx 2.8.12` and `wx 2.9.4`.